# No video from PC when using graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have my graphics card plugged in and I get no video output. I take it out and everything works as it should but when I put in the graphics card my video stops working. Everything is plugged in the right way as far as I can see. How can I solve this?

Specs:

- Processor: Core i3 3.6ghz 2 cores
- Motherboard: Asus H81M-A
- PSU: Be quiet 500w
- Ram: Vengeance LP 4GBx2
- SSD: 250GB Crucial
- Graphics Card: AMD Asus R7 360 OC

Comment: So when you remove the card, the rest of the PC works fine with the integrated graphics? Are you switching on the fly or do you shutdown the PC before switching the card in and out?

Comment: I turn of the computer and take out the graphics card and restart no video. Yes the rest of the pc works with integrated graphics however the pc is a gaming pc.

Comment: Is this a newly purchased card? What is the card exactly and what are the specs of your PC?

Comment: What about your drivers? Are they installed? If they are installed, have you tried reinstalling them?

Comment: It's a newly build pc.

Comment: If it is newly built and you haven't had a chance to install drivers, it would really help to know the specifications of the computer and its parts, especially the PSU.

Comment: I have installed the drivers. The os it windows 8.1.

Comment: Your parts should be fine and the PSU should be strong enough for the card. Is there any chance you can test the card on another machine? If not, it sounds like you just got a bad card.

Comment: Well no I'm a first time builder. But i got service for it but they said it was good.